# (Dictated) text in Google Translate iPhone App doesn’t delete with X

Tags: ios, applications, google

Google translate has a little X in the upper right of the area where you enter the text you want to be translated:

[image]

When you access Google translate using the web interface on Google Chrome and either macOS or iOS this X causes all entered text to be deleted, as expected.

But in the iOS Google translate app it doesn’t consistently work. For example if you enter text by typing with the keyboard and click the X it works, but if you enter that same text by dictation it doesn’t work. Does anyone know a way to make it work?

I have tried to use Feedback to let the developers know about this but there has been no change. It is not so easy to delete text without this feature working. You either have to click the delete key over and over and over, or select all the text and then delete — both of which are a lot more tedious than just clicking the X.

I’m using iOS 13.3 on an iPhone XR